# Express.js - How to check if headers have already been sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response-headers

I am writing a library which may set headers. I want to give a custom error message if headers have already been sent, instead of just letting it fail with the "Can't set headers after they are sent" message given by Node.js. So how to check if headers have already been sent?

Comment: powerboy would you be able to accept the other answer, because the currently accepted answer doesn't work anymore? See @fiatjaf 's comment.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**EDIT: as of express 4.x, you need to use res.headersSent. Note also that you may want to use setTimeout before checking, as it isn't set to true immediately following a call to res.send(). [Source](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2109)**

Simple: Connect's Response class provides a public property "headerSent".

`res.headerSent` is a boolean value that indicates whether the headers have already been sent to the client.

From the source code:

```
/**
   * Provide a public "header sent" flag
   * until node does.
   *
   * @return {Boolean}
   * @api public
   */

  res.__defineGetter__('headerSent', function(){
    return this._header;
  });
```

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/patch.js#L22

Comment: Note that this is not the same as http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent In express it seems to return the headers sent.. rather than a bool of if the headers have been sent.

Comment: Everyday I admire how is nodejs easy concept.

Comment: @powerboy Node currently supports res.headersSent natively, so it's probably a good idea to to start using that property.

Comment: As of May 17, 2014, res.headerSent has been deprecated by senchalabs/connect in favour of res.headersSent.

Comment: it's `headersSent`not `headerSent`

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect the headersSent thing, as it is accepted but is now misleading.

Comment: @MalcolmOcean  setTimeout of how much?

Comment: Seems it doesn't work to just use zero... I have mine set to 250ms to be safe, but fewer would probably be fine.

Comment: i flagged this answer for moderation. `res.headersSent` answer should be the accepted solution as this one no longer works.

Comment: Where is this documented that headersSent is set asynchronously?

Answer (score 224):

Node supports the `res.headersSent` these days, so you could/should use that. It is a read-only boolean indicating whether the headers have already been sent.

```
if(res.headersSent) { ... }
```

See http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent

Note: this is the preferred way of doing it, compared to the older Connect 'headerSent' property that Niko mentions.

Comment: This should be made the accepted answer seeing as the current accepted answer no longer works.

Answer (score 17):

Others answers point to Node.js or Github websites.

Below is from Expressjs website: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.headersSent

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(res.headersSent); // false
  res.send('OK');
  console.log(res.headersSent); // true
});
```